# How to inject a custom (non-bean) value to JAX-RS resources?

Tags: jax-rs, cdi

With following JAX-RS resource class,

```java
@Path("/myresource")
class MyResource {

    @GET
    public Response readSomeValue() {
        // ...
    }

    @Inject
    private int someValue;
}
```

How can I inject `someValue`?

I'm using `org.glassfish.jersey.bundles:jaxrs-ri` with Spring on Apache Tomcat. No EJBs.

I, so far, found this.

```java
/**
 * Is this gonna work?
 */
class SomeValueProducer {

    @Produces
    public int produceSomeValue() {
        /// ...
    }
}
```

1. Is this the only way? Using `@Procudes`?
2. Where can I place the producer class? Just alongside the resource class?
3. Do I need a `beans.xml`?
4. Do I need a qualifier annotation?

Thanks.

Comment: Does what you have so far work?

Comment: Spring and CDI are two different DI solutions. Spring is not compatible with CDI and vice versa. So be sure of the DI framework you want to use. If you're on a Java EE server like Glassfish, TomEE or Wildfly, CDI makes sense otherwise Spring will probably more straightforward. Tell us what is your environment and what DI solution you want to use.

Comment: @AntoineSabot-Durand I'm targeting JAX-RI and Tomcat only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *Is this the only way? Using @Procudes?*

   - Yes
2. *Where can I place the producer class? Just alongside the resource class?*

   - doesnt matter, every jar with a valid beans.xml should be scanned from the framework if configured correct: including every package in your project.
3. *Do I need a beans.xml?*

   - yes
4. *Do I need a qualifier annotation?*

   - yes, without a qualififer every method which returns an `int` value is a possible source for an injection.